# Cannot delete Laravel Application cache from deployment script

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to setup a deployment script for my Laravel 5 app to use with CodeShip but I am having issues with clearing the application cache during the deployment.

By running

> php artisan cache:clear

it does not give any errors and says the cache has been cleared but it hasnt, then when I ssh into the box and try to delete the cache manually it says permission is denied, so I need to use sudo which is not ideal as Id like to have this all to run without my intervention. I know this is a permissions issue but I cannot work out a way around it.

Is there a way I can do this or maybe a slightly different method?

Comment: have you tried composer dump-autoload?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete cache manually. Try to run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I know I shouldnt delete cache manually, but I have no other option as php artisan cache:clear does not clear the cache so I have to do it manually. I have tried every artisan command there is but it still dosnt clear. It is something to do with the user I use to deploy the app is different to www-data, therefore the deploying user wont have permission to delete the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try `php artisan config:cache`
This will do it all for you.

Hope this helps!